# Create guest login as authentication for shinymanager

Tags: r, authentication, shiny

In my shiny app I am trying to create a guest login button for users who dont have credentials yet. The idea is when the login using guest credentials, they can only see a very basic part op the application.

When the login_guest actionbutton is pressed, i was expecting to check the credentials with the specific user and password. But I dont get any responses or error messages.

Here is an example of my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinymanager)

# define credentials
credentials <- data.frame(
  user = c("user1", "user2", "guest"),
  password = c("user1", "user2", "guest"),
  admin = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h2("My secure application"),
  verbatimTextOutput("auth_output")
)
# Wrap your UI with secure_app
ui <- secure_app(ui = ui,
                 tags_top = tags$p(actionButton(inputId = "login_guest", label = "Continue as guest"))
)

# Define server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # login as guest
  observeEvent(input$login_gast, {
    res_auth <- secure_server(
      check_credentials = check_credentials(credentials)("guest", "guest")
    )
  })

  # check_credentials returns a function to authenticate users
  res_auth <- secure_server(
    check_credentials = check_credentials(credentials)
  )
  
  # Show user info
  output$auth_output <- renderPrint({
    reactiveValuesToList(res_auth)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I searched for other packages where I could use a 'guest' login, but unfortunatly I couldn't find any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In observeEvent, you are looking for input$login_gast, but you should be looking for input$login_guest

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Updating the typo doesn't solve this problem (at least not in 2023 - some things may have changed in the past few years). Although, I did find a helpful discussion on this topic in a [shinymanager issue on GitHub](https://github.com/datastorm-open/shinymanager/issues/169). This workaround is a bit hacky, as it requires accessing some shinymanager internals using `:::` but it seems to do the trick as of the current version.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinymanager)

# define credentials
# (I think you don't technically need a "guest" user for this to work)
credentials <- data.frame(
  user = c("user1", "user2", "guest"),
  password = c("user1", "user2", "guest"),
  admin = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h2("My secure application"),
  verbatimTextOutput("auth_output")
)
# Wrap your UI with secure_app
ui <- secure_app(ui = ui,
                 tags_top = tags$p(actionButton(inputId = "login_guest",
                                   label = "Continue as guest"))
)

# Define server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # login as guest
  observeEvent(input$login_guest, {
    token <- shinymanager:::.tok$generate("guest")
    shinymanager:::.tok$add(token, list(user = "guest", role = "guest"))
    shinymanager:::addAuthToQuery(session, token, "en")
    session$reload()
  })

  # check_credentials returns a function to authenticate users
  res_auth <- secure_server(
    check_credentials = check_credentials(credentials)
  )
  
  # Show user info
  output$auth_output <- renderPrint({
    reactiveValuesToList(res_auth)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```